# How to split a specific part from String(Javascript)?

Tags: javascript

Given the three formatted distance strings, how can I extract just the distance number?

```js
x = "Max, 156km from you(001)"
a = "Nick, 66km from you(131)"
b = "Niclas, 76km from you(224)"
```

```js
console.log(distance_from_x, distance_from_a, distance_from_b)
// Expected: (156,66,76)
```

Comment: Use a regular expression that matches digits followed by `km`.

Comment: isn't it the values in the () ?

Comment: Do you want the values with the KM (156,66,76)  or some kind of accumulated value of the values in the brackets? What is the rule here?

Comment: Shouldn't `distance_from_b` be `76`, not `224`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

`(\d+)km`

example you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/7tkSrn/1)

Comment: @shikida https://regex101.com/r/7tkSrn/2 and? it works.

Comment: "Nick, 66km from you(131)" => 131, not 66

Comment: I think he made misprint, because the first two have one pattern

Answer (score 0):

This should work

const regex = /[0-9]+km/gm;

Comment: You should be capturing the numbers so that you won't have to remove the last two characters

Comment: Yea, but it doesn’t make sense for the first two cases in that case.

Comment: someone is kidding you and changing the question every minute